# why, my mute role event stopps all commands from working

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm trying to make a user mute command and event i’ve got the command working but now the event is preventing any and all commands from working only events respond now even if user is not muted, but when user does have muted role their messages are properly deleted, please help

```py
 @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    channel = bot.get_channel(1060922421491793981)
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=1060693595964842165)
    if role in message.author.roles:
        await message.delete()
        await channel.send(f"@{user.display_name} **You are muted, You cant do this right now**")
```

Answer (score 0):

command arguments are always strings, except the first argument `ctx` which is the [context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context). What you can do in this case is derive the user from the mention in the `ctx` which you can get from [`ctx.message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions), so in this case you can make something like this.

```py
@bot.command()    
async def mute(ctx, user: str, duration_arg: str = "0", unit: str = "m"):
    duration = int(duration_arg)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id=1060693595964842165)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Muted {user} for {duration}{unit}")
    await ctx.message.mentions[0].add_roles(role)
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {user} was unmuted")   
    
    
@bot.event
@commands.has_role("Muted")
async def on_message(message):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if role in message.author.roles:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("You cant do this")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Also two notes:

1. try not to write the type in the variable name. We know that the `roleobject` is an object, as everything in python is an object. Using `role` is sufficient enough.
2. You might not want to wait during an async function for something like this. Instead I suggest you look into [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks), and have some sort of mechanism that stores who is currently muted, in case the bot gets turned off

Comment: i'm getting an error in the log now that says server is not defined in the case of fetching the role in the event block which is still the same issue i’ve been having

Comment: i attempted a fix but with this fix now the enitre bot is broken and only the events work no commands are recognized but when user has muted role their messages are properly deleted ugh so frustrating

```py
   
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=1060693595964842165)
    if role in message.author.roles:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send("You cant do this")```

Comment: ah you need ``await bot.proccess_commands(message)``, I also see the mistake, using ``server.`` Instead of ``message.guild.``

Answer (score 0):

found the error was missing a process line

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

event now works